# Switching from WCF to network library

Tags: c#, wcf, networking

Currently, I use WCF for my project to do networking. However, I would like to switch to some network library, Lidgren Network for example.

Since it's WCF, it uses interfaces, can send & receive data with one method, and Lidgren Network is a bit at lower-level, that you need to build and send your packets, which isn't a problem.

The problem is, that I don't have any ideas, how I can send and receive with just one method, like with WCF.

Let's say I got some client code with WCF:

```
void SomeCode()
{
    var status = wcfChannel.CheckUserId(id);
    if (status)
    {
        // true
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // false
        // do something
    }
}
```

And with lidgren network would be:

```
void SomeCode()
{
    var packet = new packet(...);
    packet.Write(id);
    var status = send2Server(packet);
    if (status)
    {
        // true
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // false
        // do something
    }
}
```

So, that 'send2Server' should be implemented somehow. Since it can receive packets only(?) in a loop, I don't have any ideas. 
Well, one - I can have some variables in SomeCode's class, and client network receiving loop on packet receive would change these variables in SomeCode's class. Also, would need to add some delay, and get these variables to further use. 
But, there should be a better way to implement this.

Comment: That better way is usually SOAP (WCF), REST (Web API / `HttpClient`) or some other protocol and accompanying libraries. Why do you want to avoid WCF?

Comment: Well, mainly because WCF doesn't work with Mono.

Comment: Most of WCF is supported in Mono, see http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/wcf/

Comment: And yet it doesn't work perfectly. My app doesn't work on Linux with Mono.
Anyway, im thinking about similar solution, after sending packet, use while(!packetReceived), after it, use method, something like ReceiveData(..). To don't have an infinite loop, check if loop counter is bigger than pre-set and break loop. So there's no other way?

Comment: WCF works well on Linux.  We use it in many of our products.  If you have a specific issue, I would open a question on that.  Going to sockets because you have a WCF issue is like building a bicycle after your car's "check engine" light came on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just noticed that Lidgren Network supports sync:

```
// create, write data to packet and send it
var packet = new packet(...);
packet.Write(id);
server.send2Server(packet);

// this will block until a message arrives
server.MessageReceivedEvent.WaitOne();

// msg is now received
var msg = server.ReadMessage();
// process received packet below
```